# Software to check browser compatibility of a website

Tags: browser, html, compatibility, web-development

Is there a software that is package to check browser compatibility with most major browser? I use browsershots.org, but it isn't that efficient because it would only return a screenshot of your website. I also use Multiple IE to check how IE renders the website. but it only checks on Internet Explorer.

I hope there is a software that is similar to browsershots where you can put your address choose different type of browsers and different versions of it. It would be a major bonus if it would a firebug or similar to the software.

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Browserlab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/)

> Adobe® BrowserLab is an online service that helps ensure your web content displays as intended. Accurately preview web pages across multiple browsers and operating systems, navigate links, and use diagnostic tools to optimize websites efficiently

Answer (score 1):

its meant for css design, but with the full version, [stylizer](http://www.skybound.ca/) has the option of switching rendering engines for checking site designs - its not free (but there's a time limited trial), but i do recall it does at least the big 3 windows browsers.

Comment: seems cool... will try this one.